# Conflict between Admob-Free and Google Maps Plugin (IONIC) in IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-admob

This is a Ionic issue using Admob-Free and Google Maps Plugin.

All clicks on the header buttons are moved down (ToogleMenu and Back button).

If you remove the Google maps or the Admob-Free everything works fine.

[image: Demo of error]

This is a project in GitHub

https://github.com/emirtrevino/myAppIOS/

Some help?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
let aidoption:AdMobOptions = {
    adId:adId,
    position:this.admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    overlap: false,
}
this.admob.createBanner(aidoption).then(() => {
    this.admob.showBanner(this.admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER);
});
```